# GSON and Ormlite - expected begin_object but was string

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am getting this gson error trying connect with my webservice

My JSON:
//city.php

```
{"City":[
         {"id":"1","estate":"2","City":"São Lourenço do Oeste"}, 
         {"id":"2","estate":"2","City":"Porto Alegre"}
        ]
}
```

My class City:

```
      @DatabaseTable(tableName = "city")
        public class CidadeModel {

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "_id", id = true)
        private int id;

        @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
        private Estate estate;

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "name_city", canBeNull = false)
        private String City;
     //getters and setters..
    }
```

Im have the class Response 
Response.class

```
    public class Response {
        public ArrayList<City> City;

        public Response(){
            City = new ArrayList<City>();
        }
    }
```

This is one Part of Connection.class

```
     private class GetCityWebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                Response response;

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String url = "http://mywebservice.com/webservice/city.php";
                HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

                try{

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

             HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream httpResponseStream =      getResponseEntity.getContent();
            Reader inputStreamReader = new     InputStreamReader(httpResponseStream);

                Gson gson = new Gson();     
                this.response = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader,Response.class);
                }       

         }

       }
```

someone can me help?
Thanks for all

Comment: How do you expect the JSON to be mapped to the POJO and why?

Comment: If i change the attribute  `private Estate estate;` to `private int estate;` in my City class, it's Work, BUT the OrmLite he does not understand the attribute `int state` is a foreign key in the database.

Comment: My Getter and Setter of the State is: `public Estate getEstate() {
  return estate;
 }


 public void setEstate(Estate estate) {
  this.estate = estate;
 }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your pojo uses Estate as type of estate, while your json uses string/int "2" - your json Parser expects the estate object to start with opening brackets but sees the string "2" instead. either fix your json (including the estate object in each city) or work with "int estate"

**update**
did you try the following json?

```
{
"City": [
         {
             "id": "1",
             "estate": {
                 "estate": "2"
             },
             "City": "Novo Horizonte"
         },
         {
             "id": "2",
             "estate": {
                 "estate": "3"
             },
             "City": "Novo Horizonte2"
         }
 ]    
}
```

With your POJOs looking like this:

```
public class City {
    public int id;
    public Estate estate;
    public String City;
}
public class Estate {
    public int estate;
}
```

FYI: the easiest way to generate valid json to test/debug/fix your bugs:

```
String json = mygson.toJson(myResponse);
```

Comment: I'm understing, but i having trying many differents json Parser with Estate object, example: {
 "City":
   [
    {
      "id":"1", 
      "Estate":{
       "estate":"2"
        },
         "City":"Novo Horizonte"
                 }
             ]
 } and not working :(

Comment: a bit late, but i just updated my answer for you - i hope it helps